# jbpm - query all unassigned tasks

Tags: jbpm

I'm using jbpm 6.2 and I'm trying to query all tasks that have not been assigned yet.
The TaskService doesn't seem to help (or at least I have not found the proper method).

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the BAMTASKSUMMARY table, not sure if it was the only way to do it.

To do that I first tried the BAMTaskEventListener at the RuntimeManager (so it started recording into the table):

```
DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory registerableItemsFactory = new DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory();
registerableItemsFactory.addTaskListener(BAMTaskEventListener.class);
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.persistence.jpa");
RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder builder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
        .newDefaultBuilder().entityManagerFactory(emf).registerableItemsFactory(registerableItemsFactory)
        .knowledgeBase(kbase);
```

With that code I had a problem, the BAMTaskEventListener didnt have an empty constructor in jbpm 6.2 and there was a problem in the instantiation...I extended it to add an empty constructor and it worked fine:

```
public class BAMTaskEventListenerExt extends BAMTaskEventListener{

    public BAMTaskEventListenerExt() {
        super(null);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BAMTaskEventListenerExt(boolean flag) {
        super(flag);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BAMTaskEventListenerExt(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        super(emf);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

And then registeded:

```
DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory registerableItemsFactory = new DefaultRegisterableItemsFactory();
registerableItemsFactory.addTaskListener(BAMTaskEventListenerExt.class);
```